# when i login xampp im getting Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function GetPagesHeader() in C:\xampp\htdocs\nnm\components\error_utils.php:76

Tags: authentication, xampp

When i login xampp im getting

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function GetPagesHeader() in C:\xampp\htdocs\nnm\components\error_utils.php:76
```